# JavaScript - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property of undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I keep getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onaudioprocess' of undefined
    at (index):144. Every time when I use the setTimeout I get the error.

```
 setTimeout(function(){
  setupAudioNodes();
  loadSound("lecture10.mp3");
}, 3000);



javascriptNode.onaudioprocess = function() {

    //get input as web param.
    var param = window.location.search.substring(1);
    //console.log(param);
    var res = param.split("%20");

    // get the average for the first channel
    var array =  new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(array);
    var average = getAverageVolume(array);

    if(average < 25.0){
      if(n > res.length-1){return;}
      console.log("First Channel : " + average);
      console.log(context.currentTime);
      //document.write(parseInt(context.currentTime));
      document.write(res[n++] + " ");
      //document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = "ssss " ;
    }

}
```

Comment: `javascriptNode` where are you getting this DOM?

Comment: Where are you defining `javascriptNode`?

Comment: Becasue `javascriptNode` is undefined!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be defining javascriptNode in setupAudioNodes() [means the node is only available after timeout period 3 sec, until that time node is not defined], If so moving the following line inside setupAudioNodes() should solve issue.

```
javascriptNode.onaudioprocess = function() { //... }
```